# How do we get buffer value using gdb

Tags: c, gdb

I would like to understand how the stack works.
I am using gdb to disassemble my code.

I disassemble the following code :

```
int main(){
   char*buf;
   buf="TEST";
   return 0;
}
```

After compiling, I run gdb and disassemble the code. 
I got this result:

```
   0x080483db <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x080483dc <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x080483de <+3>: sub    $0x10,%esp
   0x080483e1 <+6>: movl   $0x8048470,-0x4(%ebp)
   0x080483e8 <+13>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x080483ed <+18>:    leave  
   0x080483ee <+19>:    ret
```

I set a breakpoint at the instruction 0x080483e8, then I run.

When I print the value at the adress `0x8048470`, I got `TEST\n` but I don't get same result when I execute the command `x\s $ebp-0x4`.
As the content of `0x8048470` has been moved to `-0x4(%ebp)`, shouldn't I get the same value at both adresses?

Comment: What output *do* you get? I'm not familiar with how gdb works but my guess is you're getting the address of the string, since that's technically what's in there.

Comment: I get "p\204\004\b".

Comment: You might consider using an IDE for (such as e. g. eclipse, code blocks, ...). The GUI interfaces usually are much easier to handle than 'raw' GDB...

Comment: If you type `x/a $ebp-0x4`, what do you see? It's probably 0x8048470. `movl $0x8048470,-0x4(%ebp)` moves that exact 4-byte quantity, not the contents of 0x8048470.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I thought about the same thing at the beginning so I tried to do it with the function int main{int a; a=3; return 0;} and the value of $ebp-0x4 was 3. So the content has been copied.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Yes, I get 0x8048470. So what you said was definitely right but if the type is an int, why the content is copied in $ebp-0x4 ?

Comment: This is a common source of confusion, and we can find a duplicate question that has a full answer for you, but briefly: C does not have a string variable type. A char * in C is a pointer to an area of memory that is assumed to be one char or a string of chars. A string literal like "TEST" is also a char *. But when you assign one char * to another char *, you're just copying the pointer, just like when you assign an int, you're just copying the int.

Comment: I got it. Thank you a lot, your explanations were very helpful.

Comment: this: `0x080483e1 <+6>: movl   $0x8048470,-0x4(%ebp)` is accessing memory where the literal "test" is at and placing the address into the stack at the upper four bytes of the 10byte allocated stack block.  I.E. this is manipulating the address of "test", not the actual characters: "test"